# Publish all documents, but filter the values in documents' array by userId

Tags: meteor

I have the following document structure:

```
ProductDocument {
    _id: "a",
    price: 12,
    starredByUserIds: [
       "user1id",
       "user2id",
       "user3id",
    ]
}
```

For security, I want to ensure that a given user cannot see the other user's starredByUserIds by performing a query through a client console.

i.e. user3 should only be able to see his own respective entry:

```
ProductDocument {
    _id: "a",
    price: 12,
    starredByUserIds: [
       "user3id",
    ]
}
```

whilst a non-logged-in user should only be able to see:

```
ProductDocument {
    _id: "a",
    price: 12,
    starredByUserIds: [
    ]
}
```

I can't seem to define the right Publish command. I'd *like* to be able to do something like:

```
Meteor.publish('Products', function() {
    return Products.find( {}, { fields: { starredByUserIds: this.userId }} );
})
```

but 'fields' doesn't accept/match arbitrary string values.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the below query should answer your requirement:

```
Products.find({}, {starredByUserIds: {$elemMatch:{$eq:this.userId}});
```

Comment: Appreciate your input, but this doesn't return all documents

Comment: Sorry, I missed the braces in the query. Can you try with the edited query? More about `$elemMatch` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch)

Comment: it just needs an extra "}" at the end. StackOverflow won't let me edit your answer to correct this.

Comment: it's almost there... but when I test it out in Robo3T it's only returning each document's "_id" and "starredByUserIds". How do I get it to also include the document's "price" field?

Comment: ok, figured it out: Products.find({}, { fields: {starredByUserIds: {$elemMatch:{$eq:this.userId}}, dummyField: 0} });

Answer (score 1):

Following snippet  would work:

```
Meteor.publish('Products', function() {
    return Products.find( {starredByUserIds: this.UserId}, { fields: { starredByUserIds: 0 }} );
})
```

**Explanation**: 
Here the query selector `starredByUserIds: this.UserId` will return documents only which has current user's Id in its `starredByUserIds` array.

I'm omitting `starredByUserIds` array while sending it to the client, because you it will either contain the current user's Id if the user is logged in or empty if the user is not logged in, you can regenerate it.

Comment: I appreciate your input, but this doesn't return all documents

Comment: All documents are not supposed to be returned, right? Documents only which has current user's Id in `starredByUserIds` array will be returned and you were expecting only those in your question

Comment: I want to return all documents, as per title, but in those documents I don't want disclose the full set of starredByUserIds - @bordalix's comment does this in a method, but not in a publication.

Comment: Okay I got your point. But you can't do that straight with a publication I guess. But you can publish all documents without the `starredByUserIds` field and fetch only the `_id` of the documents which has current user's Id in `starredByUserIds` array and then manage them in front end(say, with React or Angular)

Comment: That could work. Might try it as a fallback if I don't succeed with an .aggregate approach

Answer (score 1):

With those security concerns, maybe you should change your data model and put the 'stars' in a different collection. If you don't want to do that, then you must change the code of your publish functions to something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('Products', function () {
  return Products.find().fetch().map(function (product) {
    if (this.userId && product.starredByUserIds.indexOf(this.userId) != -1) {
      product.starredByUserIds = [this.userId];
    } else {
      product.starredByUserIds = [];
    }
    return product;
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tested this snippet? I guess this might not work, because a publication returns only a cursor or an array of cursor, but you are returning array of object!

Comment: This does return the intended data structure (i.e. all documents), but doesn't work in a publication as @mostafizrahman mentions